# SAS: conditional statement error?

Tags: sas

Could you please help me understand why this statement is incorrect (from a quiz). For some reason I can't see a problem.

```
if total = 140 then status EQ 'works';
```

Thanks!

Comment: For those interested, the actual error displayed from running this code is `ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eq` is the comparison equals operator, not the assignment equals operator.  `=` performs both roles.

So,

```
if total eq 140 then status='works';
```

would be perfectly legal.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I guess the following way it would be correct too: if total = 140 then status = 'works';

Comment: Absolutely.  `eq` and similar (`lt`,`gt`,`le`,`ge`) are called mnemonic operators (because they sound like the words they're operators for).  They're great for making easy to read code, and I highly recommend using them; but certainly the standard operators (`= < > <= >=`) .